# Javascript GET file in enclosing folder

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, get, httprequest

I'm trying to get the JSON contents of a file via JSON, but I can't get it to work. My file tree looks like this:

- root

  - js

    - script.js
  - json

    - data.json

I can't reach the `data.json` file from my Javascript script. Here's my code:

```
var data, request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
request.open('GET', '../json/data.json'); // This works fine when the script is placed in the root and the ../ is removed, but when I move it into the js folder it breaks.
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status==200)) {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        if (data) {
            return data;
        } else {
            return "No data found";
        }
    }
}
request.send();

console.log(data);
```

The expected result is it returns an object from the JSON folder or print "No data found". Instead I just get `undefined` in my console. This means my only problem is actually finding that file. I don't normally use JavaScript so I'm probably just not using the right syntax, but since `../json/data.json` clearly is incorrect, what is?

Comment: Ajax requires an url, not a relative path. If you're running your code on a server you should get the actual url of your json file like `http://localhost/json/data.json`

Comment: I tried `file:///Users/...path_to_root.../root/json/data.json` but it's not working. I'm not running it on a server. (On OS X)

Comment: In that case, you should check for status 0 instead of 200. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file/14446538

Comment: That still didn't work. My new code:

`...if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status==0)) {...`

Comment: Check out the question I referenced. Also, try opening your url in the browser and see if it works

Comment: Yeah I'm doing everything in that question, and the URL does work. I updated my if statement to check for both 200 and 0 and it's still not returning anything. I put a console.log in the code and it just wont run